# How to read preloaded object for testing?

Tags: ruby

I don't have idea, how to read object alpha in ruby script e.g. in created method. Below it's test code using in [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/what-is-my-name-score-number-1/). Program reads letters from string in name_score and sum values each of them.
'Mary Jane' -> 3+1+4+5...

```
$alpha={'ABCDE'=>1,'FGHIJ'=>2,'KLMNO'=>3,'PQRST'=>4,'UVWXY'=>5}

Test.describe("Basic tests") do
Test.assert_equals(name_score('Mary Jane'), {"Mary Jane"=>20})
Test.assert_equals(name_score('Luke Skywalker'), {"Luke Skywalker"=>41})
Test.assert_equals(name_score('Zoe Andrews'), {"Zoe Andrews"=>23})
Test.assert_equals(name_score('Double  Space'), {"Double  Space"=>25})
Test.assert_equals(name_score('Greg Z MacDonald'), {"Greg Z MacDonald"=>26})
end
```

Comment: `$alpha` is a global. Nothing could be easier than using a global. Just, you know, _use_ it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, my question probably is the most stupid in stackoverflow. Thank you, very much!